# Wind turbine design question

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, voltage, renewable-energy

I am planning to design a wind turbine that is has rotor blade radius of 0.915m and is connected to a generator. The generators specifications are, it is an ac generator with 5000 coil turnings and a 0.050 tesla magnet with area being 1 m2
2
. The generator rotating at 135rpm producers 3534.29 V. The fan has 6 blades and when the wind velocity is 10m/s, the rotor will be going at 36.53 rpm (counting the efficiency of 35%). So, to get to the 135 rpm, gears will be used.

My question is, will the wind velocity be able to move the fan to 36 rpm when the gears will be attached to turn the generator at speed of 135 rpm?

Also, how can you figure out the theoretical yield of current that can be produced by the generated or is the current only found experimentally by attaching a load?

Comment: The answer is "it depends". If there is a load on the generator, it's possible that your wind is not strong enough. If there is no load, and the friction in your gear box is low enough - then maybe. In general, if the load is greater you need to change the attack angle of the fan blades for optimal efficiency. But this is really more an engineering question than a physics question... I recommend that you ask the question on the engineering.stackexchange site

Comment: Why would you make such an insanely large generator (with a magnetic field that is waaaaay too small to be useful) for a tiny wind turbine? And what's with the insane choice of voltage? At most you can get 540W out of this rotor at that wind speed. A commercial generator for that much power almost fits into one hand these days. May I suggest you get yourself an engineering textbook about these things?

Comment: Agreed that the most power that can be generated by rotor is 540W (this is wind related, not generator related), however, if the rotor moves at 135 rpm, with the proposed generator, it will be able to produce 3534.29 V. I would love if you suggest a textbook. Also, how large is this generator going to be? (As you can see, I am not a genius on this topic). Also, how large ca my magnetic field strength be (Earth's was near 65 microtesla at the surface so I taught that would be the upper level)?